# Using UUID for id on Pages

Tags: wagtail

Just getting started with Wagtail. To support interoperability with a legacy system, I'd like to have the id/pk of my Page objects be UUIDs instead of Integers. I tried just adding a `id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)` to my class that inherits from `Page` but I get an error `Local field u'id' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'Page'`

Is there a simple way to make `id` be a UUID? Or, do I just need to call it something besides `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be a simple way to do this, unfortunately - the assumption that IDs are numeric is baked in to the database schema, URL routes, rich text data representation and various other places in Wagtail's design.

Would it be an option to add your UUID column as a new field on your model (named something like `legacy_id`), and look up on that whenever you need to interoperate with the legacy system - but otherwise leave the primary key as numeric?

Comment: Yep, in thinking about it, that makes sense. That's exactly what I'll do, just add a separate UUID field for legacy uses.